# How to display or pass camera capture image into other views in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to i phone programming.Once i capture picture that picture iam displaying in same view,after applying image filter effect i have taken preview button  if i click on preview button means same image i want to display in another view but image is not going to next view.how can i do this can any body help me.Inside preview button i have given this below code
Thanks

```
preview *p=[[preview alloc]init];
p.secondimageviewobject= firstimageviewobject.image;
[self presentModalViewController:p animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for this kind of method, you would have to create a **singleton class** like `ShareClass.h` or if you are really new (and dont know about this) , in the `AppDelegate.h` wherein you would have to declare a `UIImage` say `UIImage *SavedImage`.

Now call this class in the view where you are capturing the image . Then save this captured image in the `SavedImage`. To share this image you would then call the `ShareClass.h` class or the `AppDelegate.h` in the view in which you want to share the image and display it in the `UIImageView`.

Any clarifications please ask. :)

In the `ShareClass.h`

```
UIImage *SavedImage;
@interface ShareClass : NSObject
{

}
```

In the Class where the image was captured, First import the `ShareClass.h`, then

```
        imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            SavedImage = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentViewController:imagepicker animated:YES completion:NULL];                
        }
```

In the Class where the image should be displayed again import the `ShareClass.h`

```
UIImageView *DisplayImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:SavedImage]];
DisplayImage.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
[self.view addSubView:DisplayImage];
```

Comment: hey thanks for giving replay.this hey iam displaying that capture image in imageview in place of image can take imageview

Comment: So fine but do u want to display in the view in which u r capturing the image ? If no then no need to add it to the imageview there , add it to the imageview in the view in which you need to display the image .... any doubts on this ??

Comment: Acctually i am taking picture and displaying in same view in imageview and after that iam applying some filter to that image then if i click on preview button i have to display that filter effect image in next view.

Comment: so save the final filtered image in the imageview and then in the saved image , then call it similarly in the next view by the process I had given u ...